# Upgrade from MW 1.18.1 to 1.23.5 broke sysop and Bureaucrat users functionality

Tags: mediawiki

Upgrade from MW 1.18.1 to 1.23.5 broke sysop and Bureaucrat users functionality

User listed in sysop and Bureaucrats MediaWiki Output receives Permission error when clicking on restricted links.

index.php/Special:ConfirmAccounts 
Permission error You do not have permission to , for the following reason: The action you have requested is limited to users in the group: Bureaucrats.

index.php/Special:UserLogin/signup 
Permission error You do not have permission to create this user account, for the following reason: The action you have requested is limited to users in the group: Administrators.

index.php?title=Special:ListUsers&group=bureaucrat 
Displays user.

index.php?title=Special:ListUsers&group=sysop 
Displays user.

Product Version MediaWiki 1.23.5 PHP 5.3.17 (apache2handler) MySQL 5.6.20-log

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It appears I have an answer.
In MediaWiki 1.18.1 logging into EDir created user names using the EDir convention: Uppercase Uppercase lowercase rest of username.....
Logging into Upgrade MediaWiki 1.23.5 forced Username to: Uppercase lowercase rest of username....
Simply editing all usernames in DB to be Uppercase first character only fixed it.